# inheritDoc: Cannot find declaraion to go to

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

Я создала комментарий к методу в интерфейсе, а в комментарии к методу класса, реализующего интерфейс, использовала `@inheritDoc`. Но почему-то *Intellij Idea* не может найти комментарий в интерфейсе, выдаёт ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема?

*P.S.* Я выполняла команду "Invalidate Caches and Restart", но это никак не решило проблему.

Comment: это с нажали кнопку мыши с ctrl? а какое поведение вы ожидаете?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, да, кнопку мыши с ctrl. Переход в класс интерфейса, к комментарию его метода... Или перехода быть не должно?)

Comment: а зачем вам переход к комментарию? нажмите ctrl+q и смотрите на ваш комментарий.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, ну и меня смущает это сообщение, "Cannot find declaraion to go to"... Похоже на ошибку

Comment: напишите баг-репорт и узнаете, что думают разработчики. думаю, что это возникает из-за того, что некоторые имеют возможность перехода.